# AS3 landing smoothly under affect of Gravity

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, hittest

I'm attempting a to make a fighting game with multiple platforms. I've successfully made the controls, movement, (double)jumping, and gravity parts of the game.

The issue is, when a player jumps, upon reaching the ground, they seem to go a bit deeper than they should on the platform (they should land and stay on the surface of the platform). This is more visible when the player double jumps.

I know why this happens; it's because sometimes `hitTestObject` takes a while to react when objects come in too quickly.

So, the first thing I thought of is to make the player's foot's `y axis` equal to the `y axis` of the top of the platform he lands on.

Though, that solution resulted in a rather jerky landing.

My question is: Is there a way to make the player to land smoothly on the top surface of the platform?

Some things I've tried:

-Raising FPS, it just made the same effect happen, but more quickly.

-Decreasing the speed at which the player falls, *but that makes the game less fun, so I've crossed it out.*

And here's my relevant code:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
var jumpConstant:Number = 30;
var gravityConstant:Number = 1.8;
function loop(e:Event):void //happens 
{
    if(player.leg1.foreleg1.foot1.hitTestObject(platforms.ground)||player.leg2.foreleg2.foot2.hitTestObject(platforms.ground)) //if either of the player's legs are colliding with the platform [ps: nested movieclips]
    {
        player.ySpeed = 0; //the player stops going downwards
        player.y = platforms.y; //the player's y becomes the platform's y. don't worry, it puts the player in the right place, just not smoothly.
        if (player.b_up) //if Up control button (W or Up Arrow) is being pressed
        {
            player.ySpeed = -player.jumpConstant; //make the player jump

        }
    else //if the player isn't colliding with the platform
    {
        player.ySpeed += player.gravityConstant; //the player is affected by gravity and is pulled downwards
    }
```

**Link to the game if you wanna try it out to see the jerky effect:**

http://www.fastswf.com/-64Ux3I

Comment: `hitTestObject` does _not_ have any form of lag based on the speed of your images - this is a total misunderstanding (or mis-statement) on your part. It simply checks if two display objects overlap.

Comment: Is the code to reset player.y before or after you increment it by ySpeed? It appears from the swf that the foot is temporarily below platform.y, causing it to bounce back up. If implemented correctly it should never get that low

Comment: @xxbbcc Apparently, I misunderstood why hitTestObject does that. I thought it was a bug in hitTestObject... Aaron's answer properly explains why hitTestObject does that. Apparently, the player only collided with the platform after a distance; thanks to the increments in ySpeed. Well, that's good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are only checking for a collision at increments of `ySpeed`. Since y speed increases during a fall by 1.8 per step, you are quickly looking at collision checks spaced widely apart. If you want pixel precise collision checks, you need to check for collision at 1px increments. This means if y speed is 10, you need 10 collision checks during one loop update. Use a for loop within your loop function to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it cleared a lot of things up. But... isn't there a better way to check if the player is colliding with the platform than a for loop? I mean, checking if the player is colliding with the platform 10 times per frame... shouldn't that make the game slower / shouldn't that be bad for resources?

Comment: There's not really a better way when using hit test. Using geometry and math there are more elegant solutions (see Box2D and Continuous Collision Detection for example) but generally any accurate solution is expensive. 10 hit tests per frame is actually a really small cost, you should only see issues in the thousands. There are many optimization techniques, too... For example you can perform very broad collision checks, and if a collision is found broadly you find the precise collision point. Also you can use spatial partitioning when numerous objects are involved.

Comment: Alright then, thanks so much for all your help ^-^   One last thing though, if it isn't too much to ask... What did you mean by "spatial partitioning"?

Comment: [Spatial partitioning](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/spatial-partition.html) is a pattern to optimize when you have many objects that can collide with each other by organizing the objects in a spatial data structure, like [a grid](http://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2009/11/as3_proximityma.html) or a [quad tree](http://lab.polygonal.de/?p=202).

Comment: Ah, interesting and pretty simple. It seems cool, but I don't think I'll be using too many objects. Thanks a lot for all the information :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set hitTestObject y coordinates a bit above the ground so the sinking into the ground will actually make it touch the ground now.

Comment: I thought of that too at first, but it's just too unreliable... besides, it turns out that I misunderstood why hitTestObject does that :/

Comment: Well, I am glad you found the answer anyways. :)